# Minifilter driver Windows 10 Differences between before and including 1809 & 1903 and above (invokes FileRenameInformation on create files)

Tags: c, windows, driver, minifilter

I have a minifilter driver that only monitored Rename and Deleted files, this worked perfectly fine up until Windows 10 1903 builds. As per code below.

Now on Windows 10 1903 & 1909 with lots of different KB tested, any time a file is created it invokes the FileRenameInformation. Is there anything that i can stop this from being invoke or identify in the request that it's creating a file, rather than a rename.

My test case is right click copy and paste a file (1MB) in a directory that is monitored for these changes.

I have also noticed that (including pre 1903) that FileRenameInformation gets invoked multiple times for renaming a file, is this normal?

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PreOperationCallback(_Inout_ 
PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
_In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, 
_Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext)
{
  PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION renameInfo;
  //WCHAR buf[4096] = { 0 };

  /* IRP-based I/O operation? */
  if (FLT_IS_IRP_OPERATION(Data)) {
  /* Open file? */
  if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {
    /* Open file for writing/appending? */
    if (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.SecurityContext->DesiredAccess &
    (FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_APPEND_DATA)) {
     return TRUE;
    }
  } else if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION) {

   switch (Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass) {

     case FileDispositionInformation:

        // deleting a file we need to action
        if (((FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION*) Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile) {
          return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, FALSE);
        }
        break;

     case FileEndOfFileInformation:

     case FileRenameInformation:

       DbgPrint("Original file - '%wZ'", name_info->Name);
       renameInfo = Data->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer;
       DbgPrint("Rename File info - '%ws'", renameInfo->FileName);

       // Process the request according to our needs e.g copy the file
       return process_irp(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, FALSE, TRUE);
     }
   }
 }

  return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}
```

Comment: `FileEndOfFileInformation` and `FileRenameInformation` common case ?

Comment: @RbMm no just the FileRenameInformation gets invoked, I don’t do anything with FileEndOfFileInformation think it has been left in the project from the original base project.

Comment: are you understand my question ? how you can know that `FileRenameInformation` gets invoked ? may be `FileEndOfFileInformation` gets invoked ?

Comment: @RbMm actually that’s a very good point. I never noticed there is no break!

Comment: Just checked and as RbMm stated the FileEndOfFileInformation was getting invoked.

Comment: I have monitored explorer's file copy which is on your test case by using procmon.exe, but the result is different with you said.

Comment: What version/build of windows 10 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Missed a break on the switch statement - change code from

```
case FileEndOfFileInformation:
case FileRenameInformation:
```

to

```
case FileEndOfFileInformation:

   // fix as per RbMm comment on SO
   break;
case FileRenameInformation:
```